# How to position popup window relative to the window top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I created a basic lightbox like thing, when a thumbnail is clicked, a popup window appears. How can I detect the top position with jQuery, so when the popup div appears it's always e.g. 200px from the window's top?

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
  $('.popup').fadeIn(300);
  $('#dark-overlay').fadeIn(300);
});

$('#dark-overlay').click(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut(300);
  $('.popup').hide();
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/EXT4H/1/

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but `position:fixed` might do it.

Comment: I want the popup to appear relative 200px to the window's viewable area. The problem is that if you click on the fifth thumbnail, the popup appears on the document's top, and it's not seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kcG9W/.  You needed to calculate the scroll offset of the window, which would make the top look like 0px, then add 200 to that so the top would appear to be 200px.

```
$('#thumbs img').click(function(){
    $('.popup').fadeIn(300);
    $('#dark-overlay').fadeIn(300);
    var top = $(window).scrollTop() + 200 + 'px';
    $('.popup').css({top:top});
});
```

Comment: Great, that's what I meant! Thanks!